# Global variable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp on Google CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to install Airflow onto a Cloud Dataproc cluster, using a CloudSQL MySQL backend.

Airflow requires that the global variable `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` be set to 1, however I cannot set this variable as the user root does not have Super_priv permissions and I have read that these permissions are not supported in CloudSQL.

Is there any way around this, so I can set this variable?

Please don't suggest using Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer myself, as per the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=on
```